# Preparing for K2 questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Just a little heads up.

I've been sent the following:

> If anyone has a K2 site with user profiles enabled and user registration enabled, watch out epic spam bombs coming nearly 5,000 user profiels registered with links to spam downloads.

So if anyone asks any questions regarding being spammed on their site using K2, you all know why and what to put ;)